# Cleaner way to strip specific character places from a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a var that is set to capture the background-image css property of an element. The result is always like this:

```
url(http://www.somerandomurltest.net/something/more/things/image.jpg)
```

I need to get rid of the "url(" and the last ")" so I only am left with the actual url, is there a function that can do this easily? I am currently doing it like this:

```
var cleanURL = urlVar.substr(0, urlVar.length-1),
    cleanURL = cleanURL.substr(4);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: How are you getting the URL in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
var str = "url(http://www.somerandomurltest.net/something/more/things/image.jpg)";
var url = str.match(/url\((.+)\)/)[1];
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7SupN/)

Comment: I always get the impression that regex is much less efficient on situations like this. Would this be quicker (Even if not noticeable) than substr?

Comment: For operations on a single string I doubt you'd ever notice a performance difference. I prefer regex as it's much more robust in dealing with changes in the input string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```
var str = 'url(http://www.somerandomurltest.net/something/more/things/image.jpg)';
str = str.slice(4, -1);
console.log(str);
```

Comment: And you don't need `str.length` there, `-1` will suffice.

Comment: `String.slice` is to little knowns its supported cross browser and is handeling both front- + backoffset (`str.slice(4, -1)`)